# Trigger server side email from JavaScript without Postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net application. I have hidden inputs that are revealed when the user clicks a JavaScript button.

I want to send an email from the server side when the user clicks the JavaScript button that reveals some of the hidden inputs.

I am trying to create a server side button, that I can set an `onclientclick` function to call my JavaScript, but also set a server side method to trigger the emails on the server side - but doing so without causing a postback.

I do not need to return anything to the page, the page will be exactly the same.

The reason I want to prevent the postback is to show the animation that takes place on the client click.

I have read about AJAX, JQuery etc.

There is no reason I can see that would make it technically unrealistic or unsafe in .net.

Maybe something along the lines of returning false after calling the server side code, or a special command that will prevent the Postback.

I do not think this issue has been directly addressed - especially as I do not need to receive anything back from the server, and is also unique because I am asking specifically about .net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a WebMethod through your .Net code and then call that WebMethod using ajax on click of that javascript button.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static bool SendEmail()
{
    //Logic to send Email        
}
```

The call will not create any postback and you can easily perform your task.

To see how to use webmethod [visit](http://www.cheezycode.com/2015/08/create-html-table-using-jquery-ajax.html).

Answer (score 0):

As you have already said, technically it is not possible. Why? Read on..

You need to understand the server-client model properly. In each communication, there is a request from client to the server and there is a corresponding response from the server to the client.

When you load a URL, the client (browser) asks the server for the page (REQUEST). The server sends the page to the client with some HTTP code (RESPONSE). After that, there is no relation between the server and the client, unless the client sends some other request.

As the name itself indicates, a "server" is one who takes order/request from the "client" and serves/responds.

In your case, since there is no request from the client, there is nothing the server can do.

Comment: why would it not be possible to send a request to the server and program the client side to not send a response? I understand this is not the convention, but I do not see why this is not possible. Or alternatively, tell the client side code to ignore the response if it is null, which it would be in this case?

Comment: Response is sent by the server, not the client. Response will not be given to the client unless there is a request to the server